# Bigger zoom level on Google Map Android application

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, maps, zooming

I'm developing an app with a 'nearby' function, listing who is connected around you on a certain position; so, markers of connected and nearby devices are listed on the map (through the **Google Map** API) and the following lines make the area zoomed:

```
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(POSITION, 21));
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
```

I would like to have a bigger zoom, I tried to change the value of 21 with bigger values, but the zoom remain the same and I've to pinch to zoom manually to see the zoomed area and markers.

Answer (score 0):

Solved in this way:

```
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(POSITION, 10));
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(16), 2000, null);
```